# IIS 7.5 - URL Rewrite

Tags: iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

How do I implement a simple rewrite to ensure that https://www.domain.com/whatever is always redirected to https://subdomain.domain.com/whatever?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This feature is ccalled canonical domain.

There's a good reference in here: 
http://thatsit.com.au/seo/tutorials/how-to-fix-canonical-domain-name-issues

Basically you add a new rule that sets a canonical domain and you enter that subdomain as the canonical domain.